# WCF Message Level Security Client Credentials

Tags: wcf, security, message, ws-security

I have some simple questions that i can't get a direct answer in any site because the variety of options in this subject.

- In Message Level Security, is **mandatory** for the client to have an installed certificate? I assume this because the server should encrypt the response message with the client Public Key and then the client decrypt it with his own Private Key.
- Is any alternative to not have the certificate in the client and have the messages encrypted in both ways(client->server) and (server->client)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have message security without the client authenticating at all. You only need a client cert if the client is authenticating via certificates

The server cert is used for securing the message in the first case. The client encrypts with the public key of the server and the server can then decrypt with its private key

If you are using secure conversation then the server cert is just used to bootstrap a session key which is then used for encryption/decryption

As long as the server cert has a full chain of trust in the client then there is no need to install the server cert on the client either

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how the client decrypts a message from the server? The client don't need a certificate that holds the private key? Or what you saying is using a secure conversation the messages are encrypted/decrypted using the session key?

Comment: If im not using a secure conversion i need to have the client cert to encryption?

Comment: Nope - looking at the messages it looks like the client generates a key and encrypts it with the server public key, the service then uses this key to encrypt the response

Comment: Final Question :) That only happens if you have the negotiateServiceCredential set to true?

Comment: No - that happens if you set it to false - if you set it to true you see the RST/RSTR messages for secure conversation